# Select non-delimiting commas with PHP and regex

Tags: php, html, regex, csv

One can immediately see the problem.  For the following .csv file using commas as delimiters, the commas inside the style attribute separating font families are being wrongly read is a delimiter, causing html to be delimited at that point.

[image]

I need a solution using PHP and regex, to select all delimiting commas, whilst ignoring all extraneous commas, and change them to a pipe symbol.

A minimal example - this

```
Trump , <span class=""font-families:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"">Make America Great Again!</span> , Senate , 55%
```

should become:

```
Trump | <span class=""font-families:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif"">Make America Great Again!</span> | Senate | 55%
```

Comment: This is not "I need a solution" type of website. Here you show your work and we tell you how you messed it up. So please make some effort yourself first.

Comment: @Dharman wth  I resent that.  I've had no sleep working on this in the past day.  I almost got ran over by a car crossing the road so tired- that's how hard I've worked.  If you don't want to help, then don't, but don't disparage others.  Sometimes people don't know where to start.  Other times they've made a legitimate effort but don't want to bias the response and want a fresh perspective.  What's it to you?

Comment: I would like to help, but if you don't know where to start then how could we? This sounds like a very broad question, it is difficult to understand what exactly you are trying to achieve. Why are the CSV values not escaped/quoted? How can you guess what is a legitimate delimiter and what is not?

Comment: afaik, the CSV values are as they are.  The CSV file was given to me as is and the onus is on me to fix it.  As for knowing how to isolate the legitimate delimiter, that's exactly the problem that if I knew the answer to I wouldn't be asking the question in the first place.

Comment: It seems you have a Space around the commas, that you want to replace. Match a Space, followed by a comma, followed by a Space, then replace with a Space a pipe and a Space.

Comment: @Poul Bak that's a great suggestion, I'm afraid it might not be foolproof, as there might be instances where someone has written `font-families: Helvetica , Arial , sans-serif` with spaces.  I just can't be sure.

Comment: It's like getting a black and white image and being asked to restore the color correctly. There is no rhyme or reason to the assembly. We could make guess but it won't work 100% of the time. The generator should be corrected.

Comment: I agree the generator should be corrected.  Unfortunately, I have no access to the generator and I have to intervene after the fact of csv creation.

Comment: You claim "I've had no sleep working on this in the past day." and yet you come here and post no code and tell us "I need a solution." What sort of reception do you expect?

Comment: @miken32 a humane one that doesn't engender contempt and malice.  I showed no code because none of my code has a good prospect of succeeding or they were all dead ends that just made the problem more complicated.  Why would I clutter and confuse the question even further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `'fontfamilies'` are always included in a `'span'` element, then you can use the following regex:

```
\s,\s((?=.*<span)|(?!.*<\/span>))
```

It matches: A `Space`, a `comma` and a `Space`. It checks that this is to the left of `'<span'` OR not to the left of '`</span>`', using a `positive look ahead` and a `negative look ahead`.

This will ignore `commas` in the `fontfamilies`, even when surrounded by `Space`.

You can test it here: [https://regex101.com/r/QDnWLY/1](https://regex101.com/r/QDnWLY/3)

Then replace with: ' `|` ' (a pipe surrounded with Spaces).

**Edit**:

To generalise, you can add more tags to the regex, like this:

```
\s,\s((?=.*<(span|div|p))|(?!.*<\/(span|div|p>))
```

Include more as you please (remember you only need those that have a font set).

**Edit2**:

To be total general (loosing some security) you can use:

```
\s,\s((?=.*<\w+)|(?!.*<\/\w+>))
```

Here the tag names are replaced by '`\w+`', meaning it will be `any Word`, but still inside tag signs.

Updated test: https://regex101.com/r/QDnWLY/4, still matches the same.

**Edit3**:

To match `commas` between the tags, you can use:

```
\s,\s(?!.*<\w+)(?=.*<\/\w+>)
```

Comment: Can we generalise this to all element types?  I mean, to be honest, even then, commas can occur outside of tags.  The reason why I can't give a general enough example to work with is we're looking at unstructured html text.  I think it's better to define in terms of what is a delimiting comma, rather than what is not.

Comment: It can be more general than specifying specific element types.  How do I get the negative of this `,(?=[^<]*>)` in regex?

Comment: I am worried about `<span class=""font-families:Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif""> Cats, dogs , rabbits </span>` - or just even `Cats, dogs , rabbits` without any html - how can we exclude these commas outside of the tags, but which are not delimiters?

Comment: I know this is extending the question a little bit so I can probably accept your answer in a short while, but I just wanted to know if there was a universal match for all commas that are not delimiters?

Comment: The cats, dogs won't be matched, since they are inside the tag. You can test in on regex link above. Outside the tags, everything is considered delimeter (regex is stupid).

Comment: In what sense do we lose security?  What did you mean by this?

Comment: All I meant is, that if some string contains something looking as a tag (but isn't) then it might be fooled. That's probably theorethical.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that you can start with

```
preg_replace("/\s{1}\,\s{1}/g","|", "Trump , .....")
```

Comment: `\s{1}` is the same as `\s`. There is no `g` modifier in PHP.

Comment: I actually can't rule out the possibility that someone wrote `font-families: Helvetica , Arial , sans-serif` with spaces flanking the commas, which would then regrettably negate this otherwise wonderful solution...